# How to access AWS cloudwatch event in Android Studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to access the Amazon AWS services using the AWS SDK but unable to authenticate the AWS.

Even I was unable to access the other CloudWatch function other than alarm and time.

Comment: Can you share logs ? what errors are you getting ?

Comment: I posted the same question in the Aws help center and got a reply that android studio cannot access cloudwatchevent services.